# Rest call without RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

WebSphere don't load previous classes (`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`) of `RestTemplate` for do a REST call with customize class to catch JSON in response. 
Now I'm trying to find an alternative to `RestTemplate` for do REST call.
Anyone have an idea?

This is my actually code but don't load previous classes so don't match JSON

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<Person> restResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(providerUrl, Person.class);
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What is the expected behavior, what happens instead? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think it's a cloassloader issue. Try to configure the classloader. In any case you may do simple http requests and parse them; it's a more complicated approach but it's possible. I strongly suggest to you to use RestTemplate

Comment: I'm in a JSF page and when I click a button, bean page bind to a JSF page make a REST call, but in debug with WebSphere I saw that don't pre-load classes, but using JVM it works.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata You have right, but I don't know how to configure classloader of WebSphere

Comment: Give a look here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/trun_classload_server.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider the following:

```
ResponseEntity<String> restResponse = restTemplate.getForEntity(providerUrl, String.class);
```

Then parse the response body yourself?